# Would/will for possibility or chance

Tags: differences, modal-verbs

Please explain the differences between using 'will' and 'would' in the examples below:

> There is a possibility he would win.

Versus

> There is a possibility he will win.

And

> There is still a chance that he will arrive before 7.

Versus

> There is still a chance that he would arrive before 7.

Both are very common but my take on it is that "will” suggests a much stronger/greater probability or future likelihood compared to "would". 
Please offer yours.

Comment: Most English speakers use *will* and *would* interchangeably without thinking about their choice. In my experience *would* is more often followed by a condition (if it doesn'nt/didn't rain, if the strike was called off).

Comment: *There is a possibility he will win* asserts that ***in the current circumstances***, he might win. But *There is a possibility he **would** win* is only meaningful in a context where it's possible some ***other*** circumstances might arise (and if they *don't,* he probably has no chance of winning).

Comment: I'm not too sure *There **is** still a chance that he **would** arrive before 7* could ever make sense.